# How is the style directive defined?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm experienced with Angular but of course, there are some things which are still beyond my understanding. I am trying to understand the directive for setting specific styles on an element, e.g.:

```
<div [style.color]="'red'">...</div>
```

My question is, how is this directive defined in code? Is there a separate directive definition for each possible style value (color, background-color, border, etc.)? Or is there one definition for a `style` directive which has internal code that retrieves the part after the `.` and behaves accordingly?

In other words, how would I define a similar attribute which can accept a `.something` after it and behave differently on different such suffixes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the source code of their [`flex-layout`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/flexbox/api/layout.ts) module, you need to define all the possible combinations you can think of in a string, and separate them by a comma:

```
@Directive({selector: `
  [fxLayout],
  [fxLayout.xs], [fxLayout.sm], [fxLayout.md], [fxLayout.lg], [fxLayout.xl],
  [fxLayout.lt-sm], [fxLayout.lt-md], [fxLayout.lt-lg], [fxLayout.lt-xl],
  [fxLayout.gt-xs], [fxLayout.gt-sm], [fxLayout.gt-md], [fxLayout.gt-lg]
`})
```

In the case of angular and their style binding, they parse it like [Günter says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033934/235648) indeed

Comment: This is useful indeed, thanks, now I can't decide whose answer to accept :)

Comment: Type this in console: `Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'PierreDuc' : 'Gunter'`

Answer (score 2):

It's built-in Angular binding syntax.
You can't build something like that yourself.

See also

-
 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_ast.ts#L219
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/binding_parser.ts#L26

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer, can you elaborate a bit? Where can I look at that internal angular code? Can you point me at the specific source file?

Comment: I added a link to my answer.